# Not able to perform actions on supportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager, google-maps-markers, supportmapfragment

I'm struggeling with this for a few hours, so I finally decided I need some help on this.

I have a SupportMapFragment (Google Map v2) in a ViewPager, the viewpager itself is in a TabFragment. It's not a pretty sight, but it's not an app made for publishing. It's more a proof of concept for a future app I'm developping.

So, the structure looks something like this:

MainActivity:

- Tab 1

  - Tab1ViewPagerFragment 1 <-- MapFragment
  - Tab1ViewPagerFragment 2
  - Tab1ViewPagerFragment 3
- Tab 2

  - Tab2ViewPagerFragment 1
  - Tab2ViewPagerFragment 2
  - Tab2ViewPagerFragment 3
- Tab 3

  - Tab3ViewPagerFragment 1
  - Tab3ViewPagerFragment 2
  - Tab3ViewPagerFragment 3

As I said, not a pretty sight, but I'm not to concerned about that.

Now, something strange is happening.
The map is showing fine, it's in the standard world-view and I can zoom/rotate/.. manually in the app.

The problem is, I cannot for the life of me show markers/zoom the camera/... programmatically.

I get the map in onViewCreated, and when I log mMap.toString() I get:

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@476b528 (for example)
```

When I add a marker, like so:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
```

it's not showing. Also, 'marker' isn't null, and I can log it's longitude and latitude, so I assume it is created successfully (somehow).

I really don't understand what's happening here.

I'm willing to add some code, but it's all a big mess after trying things for a few hours, so if you give me some pointers on what you need to see, I'll clean it up a little and post it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Since I don't know where to begin adding code. I'll start with OnCreatedView:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = 
                         (SupportMapFragment) GameFragment.mGamePagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(0);

    if (supportMapFragment == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > supportMapFragment == null");
        mMap = null;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > supportMapFragment != null > supportMapFragmentToString: " + supportMapFragment.toString());
        mMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    }


    if (mMap == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > mMap == null");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > mMap != null > mMap: " + mMap.toString());

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null");

            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(51.2, 4.5));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

            mMap.moveCamera(center);
            mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
            if (marker == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker == null");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker != null");
                LatLng location = marker.getPosition();
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker != null > MarkerToString: " + marker.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker != null > Marker Latidude: " + location.latitude);
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker != null > Marker Longitude: " + location.longitude);
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated > savedInstanceState == null > marker != null > Camera Position: " + mMap.getCameraPosition().toString());
            }
        }

    }
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I guess you'll need the 'getRegisteredFragment'-method from the GamePagerAdapter;

```
public Fragment getRegisteredFragment (int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}
```

the fragments are kept in a SparseArray, and are stored there in the instantiateItem-method

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;        
}
```

**UPDATE**

I pulled the SupportMapFragment out of the ViewPager and gave it it's own tab. Now It's working fine.

Still this doesn't answer this question ofcourse, but my problem is solved.